# Releasing all buttons that dynamically created in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

Now i developing IOS application with XCode4.2. i create UIButton when the application run. so my coding is here:

```
- (IBAction)btnSync_Click:(id)sender {
    float j=10.0;
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(j, 170, 100.0, 50.0);
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"btn%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [fra_btn addSubview:button];
        j=j+110;
    }
}

- (IBAction)btn_Click:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btntmp=(UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(btntmp.titleLabel.text);
}
```

i want to know that i still need to release all buttons inside the fra_btn(View)? if yes how should i do it? my project is ARC project.

Best Rgds,
df

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to release this buttons, and any other objects from CocoaTouch framework created programmatically under ARC.

Answer (score 1):

As you does not use alloc--Init for button initialization you do not need to release any thing

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wolvorins answer:

Only methods that only methods that start with `init`, `new`, or `copy` assume you own the object, so only objects you obtained with a method starting with the above three keywords do you have to release. All other methods should be autoreleased. (There could be a lousy programmer that ignores this rule, but Apple isn't lousy, so you can safely apply this to the Cocoa classes.)

This is (perhaps 'obviously') also applies to `alloc`, `copy` and `new`.

But Tomasz Wojtkowiak is right. ARC is `Automatic Reference Counting`, so you don't have to release anything, that's exactly the job of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

in ARC however release is refrained,so no question of releasing any iVar.And as per the question UIButton here is not being allocated using alloc, init.Similar example of this would be when you allocate a string say `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];` or `[NSArray arrayWithObjects];`which are autoRelease .Explicitly releasing them will cause the app to crash at that line

Answer (score 0):

you cannot release the button you created since you did not use alloc. So it did not allocate memory.Hope this will help you.